# Display vertica records vertically in vsql

Tags: database, vertica, vsql

I am look for a command in vsql which is equivalent of \g in mysql console, because I need display the result set vertically, looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the **\x** option.

For more formatting options use the **\help** command .

```
dbadmin=> select 1,2;
 ?column? | ?column?
----------+----------
        1 |        2
(1 row)

dbadmin=> \x
Expanded display is on.
dbadmin=> select 1,2;
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | 1
?column? | 2

dbadmin=> select 1,2;
 ?column? | ?column?
----------+----------
        1 |        2
(1 row)

dbadmin=> \x
Expanded display is on.
dbadmin=> select 1,2;
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | 1
?column? | 2
```